# Writing query to extract specific data from SQL Server XML data column

Tags: sql-server, xml, field

I am trying to run a query such that the row set will return the contents of the  element.  below is my query, and a sample of the data in the XML column.  what gets returned in the column Address is all NULL's.  But I know there is data in that element in the table.   What am I doing wrong.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES( 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap' AS  "soap")

SELECT  
Data.value('(/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/Report/Location/Address/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Address
FROM Mytable

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <soap:Body>
        <Report>
          <Location>
            <Address>600 BENNETT ST</Address>
          </Location>
        </Report>
      <soap:Body>
<soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a wrong XML namespace - you're missing the closing `.../envelope`. Also, it seems you cannot use "soap" as the XML namespace alias in XQuery - not sure why.

Try this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS se)
SELECT  
   Data.value('(/se:Envelope/se:Body/Report/Location/Address/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') 
     AS 'Address'
FROM Mytable
```

In my test case, this way it appears to be working.